# How do I execute a command on login for a system user with no home folder and no personal .bashrc file?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, users, su, bashrc

I set these users' home folders through the /etc/passwd file, but when they log in I would like them to activate a python virtualenv. If they had a personal `.bashrc` file, I'd just include the `activate` command there, and the directory change as a post-activate hook with virtualenv.

However these users don't have home folders, and don't have personal `.bashrc` files.

How can I execute a different command on login for each of these users? (Only one command needs to be executed.)

These users are only logged into using `su`, never SSH. The machine is a VPS running Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 8):

You can add a file to the system's `/etc/profiile.d` directory that includes a `if/then` statement for each of the users that you want to run the `virtualenv` for.

#### Example

Say I create a file like this, `/etc/profile.d/me.sh`.

```
if [ "$USER" == "saml" ]; then
  touch /tmp/samsfile
fi
```

Make it executable:

```
$ chmod +x /etc/profile.d/me.sh
```

And then login as `saml`, using `su`:

```
$ su saml
```

If we check to see if the temp file was created, it was:

```
$ ls -l /tmp/samsfile 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Oct 14 00:31 /tmp/samsfile
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is define environment variables, you can put them in [`~/.environment`](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_env.html) in the users' home directory. You can put more complex shell snippets in `~/.profile`.

All user accounts do have a home directory, even if it doesn't belong to them. While you can have accounts whose home directory doesn't exist, there isn't much point to doing that. You can use a single directory owned by root as the home directory of these users if you like.

Another possibility to execute a command at login time would be to add [`pam_exec`](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_exec.html) to the PAM stack. But beware that this is quite tricky to use correctly, because the program runs as the *original* user, or as root, and not as the target user, and it runs in the environment chosen by the original user so it's hard to make it secure if it's running as root.